# Oracle Sum with $ symbol

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sum the field which has a `$` symbol next to the number. I am using the below code but I get an "Invalid Number" error.

This field is already a VARCHAR2 type.

```
SELECT FILER_CD,P ORT_ENT_CD, ENT_TYP_CD, 
       TO_CHAR(Sum(VAL_AMT),'$9,999,999.99') AS SUM_AMT
FROM AMT_TABLE
GROUP BY FILER_CD, PORT_ENT_CD, ENT_TYP_CD, VAL_AMT;
```

Comment: Why is `val_amt` a `varchar2`?  Things that you want to sum ought to be stored as numbers in the table.  Adding a dollar sign and/or formatting the number to include thousands separators are things that should be handled at the display layer not in the table definition.

Comment: Probably you want `to_number` not `to_char`, and to have that inside the sum

Answer (score 1):

If column contains `$`, remove it.

```
sum(replace(val_amt, '$', '')) as sum_amt
```

If column is formatted *differently* (group and/or decimal symbols), you'll have to fix that as well because you can't sum *strings*. Sample data might help us help you.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to remove the $ sign and then reinsert the records into a new table.